# How to load an image from a function in another class in UICollectionView? I'm using paint code

Tags: swift, paintcode

I have a collection view which will have to load the content of the cells but I don't want to use images from assets. So, I create a class with Paint Code which draws some images for me. However, I don't know how to load the images that paint code drew for me in my UICollectionView cells using dequeueReusableCell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna usa a `TableView` as example, but it's the same thing with a `UICollectionView`...

Create a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`.
In this example I'm calling it `ItemCell`:

```
class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {...}
```

Create and configure  a `.xib` file.
This file lays out your cell, and holds a `UIView` that represents your PaintCode drawable:

[image: customCell]

In Storyboard, set the class of your `UICollectionViewCell`s as your custom subclass (in this example `ItemCell`).
The key thing here is to give it an **identifier**, so it can be `dequeued`:

[image: configuration]

Code example to reuse your custom cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    // Constants.itemCellName matches the above identifier.
    if let itemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.itemCellName) as? ItemCell {
        configure(itemCell, at: indexPath)
        cell = itemCell
    }

    return cell
}
```

Profit:

[image: example]